# iphone app text field doesn't work correctly

Tags: iphone

I'm currently working on an Iphone application that has 3 text fields. If I connect the delegate of the first two text fields to the class then run the simulator and try to click on them nothing happens, they don't allow me to edit them and the keyboard doesn't pop up. If I don't connect their delegates then the keyboard appears but textFieldShouldReturn is never called when I click the done button on the keyboard. The third text field brings up a UIPickerView when clicked on and that shows up as expected.

LoginViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController     <UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>
{
IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField;
IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
IBOutlet UITextField *conferenceField;
IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;
//IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
ConnectHandler *cHandle;    
NSMutableArray *conferences;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *usernameField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *passwordField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *conferenceField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *loginButton;

- (IBAction) login: (id) sender;

@end
```

LoginViewController.m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"


@implementation LoginViewController

@synthesize usernameField;
@synthesize passwordField;
@synthesize conferenceField;
@synthesize loginButton;

// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization.
}
return self;
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
cHandle = [ConnectHandler new];

NSArray *confs = [cHandle conference_list];
//conferences = confs;

// temporary to test if it's working
conferences = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Germany", @"Austria", @"Swiss", @"Luxembourg", 
               @"Spain", @"Netherlands", @"USA", @"Canada", @"Denmark", @"Great Britain",
               @"Finland", @"France", @"Greece", @"Ireland", @"Italy", @"Norway", @"Portugal",
               @"Poland", @"Slovenia", @"Sweden", nil];

UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.dataSource = self;
[picker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
[conferenceField setInputView:picker];
[picker release];
[picker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];

}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {
NSLog(@"TextFieldShouldReturn");
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations.
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
[conferences release];
}

- (IBAction) login: (id) sender
{
loginButton.enabled = FALSE;

NSLog(@"user: %@ pass: %@", usernameField.text, passwordField.text);
//checks to see if user provided information is valid
NSString *db = @"sdfsdf";

BOOL auth = [cHandle check_auth:db :usernameField.text :[cHandle hashPass:passwordField.text]]; 
NSLog(@"AUTH: %@", auth?@"YES":@"NO");
// login successful if check_auth returns YES
if (auth == YES) {
    // store the user's login info
    // switch to full app


    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
else {
    // display error message and stay on login screen
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Invalid"
                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The login or password you have entered is invalid"]
                          delegate:nil 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" 
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    loginButton.enabled = TRUE;
}

//NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
//[pickerView setHidden:NO];
}


//#pragma mark -

//#pragma mark UIPickerViewDelegate

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
NSLog(@"titleForRow");
return @"TEST"; //[conferences objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
NSLog(@"didSelectRow");
[self textFieldShouldReturn:conferenceField];
//  [pickerView resignFirstResponder];
//conferenceField.text = (NSString *)[conferences objectAtIndex:row];

}

//#pragma mark -

//#pragma mark UIPickerViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
NSLog(@"numberOfComponentsInPickerView");
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInComponent");
return 4; //[conferences count];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your viewDidLoad:

```
usernameField.delegate = self;
passwordField.delegate = self;
conferenceField.delegate = self;
```

You're not settings the delegate for the text fields. Also remove the `resignFirstResponder` code from your `textFieldDidBeginEditing` as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: Sure thing! Glad to help (: *Upvoting your question for actually explaining the problem*

Comment: Please select my answer as correct if you feel so (:
Again, glad to help. Setting the delegate is something a lot of people forget.

Answer (score 0):

You have `[textField resignFirstResponder]` in the delegate method `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:` which would make the keyboard go away prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    //[pickerView setHidden:NO];
}
```

With the delegate hooked up, it’s receiving the `-textFieldDidBeginEditing:` message when the user touches the text field and immediately forcing the text field to resign first-responder status (i.e. lose its keyboard). Keep the delegate connected, remove the `-resignFirstResponder` call, and it’ll work.